# How to organise inputs without using <form> everytime

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML and I had some problems today with the page on the picture, I wanted to have the e-mail input under the First Name (just like the picture) input but when I first tried, it just went to the right of the page, right after Last Name, so I had to close the `<form>` and open it again so it would move a block below. Is there another way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us some code so we can see what you have already?

Comment: Either enclose anything you want in a separate block in a `<fieldset>`, `<div>` or just insert a `<br />` element before a new group starts.

Comment: Note that the form element groups the field which will be sent through the post request. If you open and close form around each field, only one field will be sent on submit.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use form on input field. There should be only one form for the whole group of fields. Just like a paper.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer is to use a `<br />` element:

```html
<h1>Course Signup Page</h1>
<form id="loginform">
  <label for="firstname">First name</label> <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <label for="lastname">Last name</label> <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <br /> <!-- you can simply insert a line-break here -->
  <label for="email">E-Mail</label> <input type="email" id="email" />
  <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" />
</form>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Another option is to wrap your rows in any appropriate block level element (**not** a `form` element though, as that will interfere with the submitting, and also form elements cannot be nested).

Block level elements have some standard rendering behaviour:

- They take as much horizontal space as they can get.
- *They cause a line-break before and after themselves.* <- The relevant part for you.
- They can be assigned `width` and `height` via CSS.

The standard element for this is `div`:

```html
<h1>Course Signup Page</h1>
<form id="loginform">
  <div>
    <label for="firstname">First name</label> <input type="text" id="firstname" />
    <label for="lastname">Last name</label> <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label> <input type="email" id="email" />
    <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This does not fix the alignment problem, though.

I'd rather suggest you make use of the power of CSS and use a CSS grid:

```css
#loginform {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, min-content));
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

#loginform label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1>Course Signup Page</h1>
<form id="loginform">
  <label for="firstname">First name</label> <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <label for="lastname">Last name</label> <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <label for="email">E-Mail</label> <input type="email" id="email" />
  <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" />
</form>
```

It has to be said though, that this requires additional effort to make it work in IE 10 / 11.